# Capturing System/out in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure

I'm working with a Java package that outputs text to the console and I need to capture that text in a string, but I'm not sure how to do this. From looking at the Clojure documentation it seemed that all I have to do is wrap the java call in `with-out-str` but that isn't working for me.

Minimal code example: if I try

```
(with-out-str 
 (.println (System/out) "foo"))
```

I'm hoping to get a string with the value "foo", but it's still outputting to the console instead. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java's `System.out.println(...)` is a call to `println` method of `PrintStream` instance. You need to replace the `System.out` stream with your own instance and capture its content:

```
(import [java.io ByteArrayOutputStream PrintStream])

(def out-buffer (java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.))

(System/setOut (java.io.PrintStream. out-buffer true "UTF-8"))

(defn out-str []
  (.toString out-buffer "UTF-8"))
```

Watch out in the REPL though because it uses `System.out` to print the results so when you replace it globally, it will break your REPL instance.

You can even write a macro that will capture the content of the `System.out` and then restore the original `PrintStream` instance:

```js
(defmacro with-system-out-str [& body]
  `(let [out-buffer# (ByteArrayOutputStream.)
         original-out# System/out
         tmp-out# (PrintStream. out-buffer# true "UTF-8")]
     (try
       (System/setOut tmp-out#)
       ~@body
       (finally
         (System/setOut original-out#)))
     (.toString out-buffer# "UTF-8")))

(with-system-out-str
  (.println System/out "Hi"))
;; => "Hi\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save output into a file then read content of the file.

```
(def foo-file (clojure.java.io/writer "foo.txt"))

(binding [*out* foo-file]
  (println "Foo, bar."))

(println "Slurp: " (slurp "foo.txt"))
```

Answer (score -1):

The Tupelo library includes both
[with-system-out-str](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/23.06.21/api/tupelo.core#with-system-out-str) and [with-system-err-str](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/23.06.21/api/tupelo.core#with-system-err-str).  These can be used alone, or in conjunction with [discarding-system-out](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/23.06.21/api/tupelo.core#discarding-system-out) and [discarding-system-err](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/23.06.21/api/tupelo.core#discarding-system-err). Together, these allow you to take full control of your unit tests.  Usage examples:

```
     (verify
       ;------------------------------------------------------------------
       ; Clojure:  clojure.core/println
       (is-nonblank= "clojure.core/println"
         (with-out-str
           (clojure.core/println "clojure.core/println")
           (+ 2 3)))

       ;------------------------------------------------------------------
       ; Java:  System.out.println
       (is-nonblank= "System.out.println"
         (t/with-system-out-str ; discards return value, yields System.out
           (doto System/out
             (.println "System.out.println"))
           (+ 2 3)))
       (is= 7 (t/discarding-system-out ; discards System.out, normal return value
                (doto System/out
                  (.println "System.err.println"))
                (+ 3 4)))
       (is-nonblank= ""
         (t/with-system-out-str ; discards return value
           (t/discarding-system-out ; discards System.out
             (doto System/out
               (.println "System.err.println"))
             (+ 3 4))))

       ;------------------------------------------------------------------
       ; Java:  System.err.println
       (is-nonblank= "System.err.println"
         (t/with-system-err-str ; discards return value, yields System.err
           (doto System/err
             (.println "System.err.println"))
           (+ 2 3)))
       (is= 5 (t/discarding-system-err ; discards System.err, normal return value
                (doto System/err
                  (.println "System.err.println"))
                (+ 2 3)))
       (is-nonblank= ""
         (t/with-system-err-str ; discards return value
           (t/discarding-system-err ; discards System.err
             (doto System/err
               (.println "System.err.println"))
             (+ 2 3)))))
```