# Unit Test console output for generated bytcode

Tags: java, clojure, bytecode

I am using  https://github.com/jgpc42/insn to generate Java Bytecode, I’m trying to have some tests like bellow. The thing is that it works fine when executing with `cider-test-run-ns-tests` but not when with `lein test` ( the `(with-out-str (eval` (. ~cname main)))`  return empty string  "" )

Any tip here?
Thanks

```
(require '[insn.core :as insn])

(defn make [& {:as m}]
  (insn/new-instance m))

 (defn sum-bt [n]
   (make
    :name 'my.pkg.Test
    :methods [{:flags [:public :static], :name "main", :desc [:void]
               :emit [[:getstatic java.lang.System "out" java.io.PrintStream]
                      [:ldc2 n]
                      [:ldc2 n]
                      [:ladd]
                      [:invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream "println" [:long :void] false]
                      [:return]]}]))


(deftest sum-bt-test
  (let [cname 'my.pkg.Test
        _ (sum-bt 4)
        result (with-out-str (eval `(. ~cname main)))]
    (is (= result "8\n"))))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capturing System/out in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773329/capturing-system-out-in-clojure)

Comment: Just replace `with-out-str` with `with-system-out-str` (in the answer of the linked question). Maybe you will have to also replace `\n` with `\r\n`.

Comment: Great, it works. Makes sense. Thanks (using the  with-system-out-str`)